# Loading table in html takes quite long time

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, performance, web

I have a big table, which takes a lot of time to load on the web. I'm looking for a solution to speed up the loading time, and I'm not looking into splitting it into various pages. Any suggestion?? Here is the link: http://khi.ac.ir/EnglishW/info/Students/All_Students.aspx

Comment: Without looking at it, I would suggest reducing or eliminating any images shown in the table.  After that, perhaps going through and making sure that any/all "non-essential" HTML gets stripped out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [loading big tables in HTML, what are other possibilities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240011/loading-big-tables-in-html-what-are-other-possibilities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you add a line like this :

```
<td style="width: 20%">
<a id="HyperLink8821120010" style="color:Black;font-family:Tahoma;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" href="StudentNumber_8821120010.aspx">آهي عاطفه</a>
</td>
```

for every entry. I suggest that first do not add `style="color:Black;font-family:Tahoma;text-decoration:none;"` for every table column and use this in a separate css file and also show just the names of the users and a little javascript to add extra information(like download links) to the next `td` element like:

```
<td>
 <a onclick="addInfoToNextColomn()">آهي عاطفه</a>
</td>
<td id="next">
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JQuery DataTables Server Side Processing to accomplish this task.

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

This would be the only way to reduce loading time because instead of loading every table row at once, It will load a set of rows at a time.

Answer (score 0):

For those searching for an answer in 2019, here are some paths I tried for a similar problem:

Create a 2D array as a variable with all your data; for me it decreased the table size from 10mb to 3mb, and can possibly decrease it further if I find repetitive long texts and substitute them with a short placeholder. This has an advantage of speeding up the download, but it decreases interpretation time.

Interpretation of a 2D array can be done with a simple string gluer or dom .appendChild builder. I find that string concatenators work the fastest.

```
function createTable(tableData) {
  var firstdiv = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  var i = 0;
  var text = "<table><thead><tr><th>Project</th><th>Planner</th><th>Item</th><th>Comment</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
  var item;
  for (i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    item = tableData[i];
    text += "<tr><td>" + item[0] + "</td><td>" + item[1] + "</td><td>" + item[2] + "</td><td>" + item[3] + "</td></tr>";
      }
  text += "</tbody></table>"

  firstdiv.innerHTML = text;
}
```